# In Excel VBA, how do you remove grey page break lines?

Tags: vba, excel

**Question:**

How do you remove grey dotted line page breaks (not the blue ones) from an Excel sheet using VBA code?

**Background:**

We have a collection of ODBC spreadsheets generated via VBA. When running two different (though similar) spreadsheets on my local box without manually changing any options in Excel, one shows dotted grey lines on the page breaks *(see image below)* and one does not. Both are large enough to extend past one page. I have not been able to find a difference in the code that gives reason to this.

Most of the advice on the internet points toward the options in Excel via the GUI, which is not an option. I am seeking a VBA solution.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried several different variations and applications of `DisplayPageBreaks = False`. Either I'm using it incorrectly, or it is not the correct setting. My most reasonable use of this property has been:

`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(str_Worksheet_Name).DisplayPageBreaks = False`

Note that the variable `str_Worksheet_Name` works in many other lines in the code, example: `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(str_Worksheet_Name).Cells(1, 1).Select` correctly selects cell `A1` on the desired worksheet.

**Reference Image:**

These are the lines I am trying to remove:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

---

**Additional Info:**

- RE Mat's Mug's comment:

It sounds like something in this code snippet is preventing them from showing up on this spreadsheet. Note that this snippet is from the sheet that correctly **does not** show the page breaks:

```
Public Function cmlapi_Set_To_Landscape()

On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .Zoom = 100
End With
If glob_Header_On_Every_Page = True Then
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$" & HEADER_OFFSET
    End With
End If
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1

End Function
```

- Per answer from Mat's Mug:

  ```
  With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
      .Orientation = xlLandscape
      .FitToPagesTall = 1
      .FitToPagesWide = 1
  End With
  ```

No luck with this. The lines are still there. Note that the `.Orientation = xlLandscape` did work, so there shouldn't be a concern of where this is specified in the code.

- Per answer from Vidyata:

`ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks` works in the immediate window (Ctrl + G) for the spreadsheet after it has been run. Rerunning puts the dotted lines back again. Oddly using this same property in the code doesn't seem to have an effect, but clearly is the correct code. Perhaps there's a specific place it needs to be? I would have thought as long as I either use `ActiveSheet` when the correct sheet is selected or specified my sheet name it shouldn't really matter.

It was further suggested that I try it on the last line. Good idea, but didn't work out either. Tried both of these on the last line in two separate trials:

`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(str_Worksheet_Name).DisplayPageBreaks = False`
`ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False`

- I tried using the PageSetup code above. That didn't do it either.

---

**Solution:** See Mat's Mug's answer. `FitToPagesTall = 1` and `FitToPagesWide = 1` worked after also setting `Zoom = False`.  I'll shamefully admit I'm rather surprised I didn't find this earlier as it is exactly stated as such on Microsoft's Dev Network site:

Link: [MSDN Info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/pagesetup-fittopageswide-property-excel)

Code:

```
 .Zoom = False 
 .FitToPagesTall = 1 
 .FitToPagesWide = 1
```

Not sure why the `Zoom` line is needed, but that was the missing piece.

Thanks to all who helped!

Comment: FWIW these indicate misplaced page breaks, giving the user a clue that printing the document as-is will likely not print as expected. Consider properly configuring the worksheet's `PageSetup` instead.

Comment: I think the `PageSetup` section of the sheet that doesn't show the lines is the reason why. Do you know what I can specify there for it have the effect of removing the dotted lines? I agree that sounds like the better solution. I'll add the snippet of code from the sheet that doesn't show them, maybe you can highlight why?

Comment: If a sheet was never viewed in PageBreakPreview mode, the lines won't appear. Configuring the `PageSetup` to "scale to fit" to 1 page wide by 1 page high will effectively move the dotted lines to where they don't matter.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into the "scale to fit" property, do you see something different in the code snippet I just added that might be taking care of it instead?

Comment: Ugh. PageBreaks API is borked.

Comment: Haha as I'm learning...

Comment: tbh those dotted lines are looking nicer and nicer

Comment: Try toggling PageBreakPreview mode on *before* you configure `PageSetup` (and then toggle it back off afterwards)

Comment: Good thought, thanks, sadly still no luck. I'm going to try copying in the PageSetup from the other sheet and see what that does.

Comment: That didn't cut it either. So there's something else conflicting with it. This is the only module referencing anything to do with formatting the worksheet, so it must be in this module somewhere. I'll keep working at it and post back if I come up with the answer. Let me know if you think of anything else. Thanks for the brainstorming

Comment: If the sheet isn't created by a macro, then you could setup its page breaks manually, save, and never think about it ever again :)

Comment: Yes... But alas, it is, and needs to be. Such is life. It's ok. Dotted lines don't take away from the data. Being a formatting guy, they're just bugging the heck out of me!

Comment: I'm out of ideas :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing any `Zoom`, and then scaling the `PageSetup` to fit a single page:

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = False
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
```

That should get the dotted lines out of the way.

Comment: No dice, my friend :(

Comment: @Jackson that's rather surprising. Stupid question: is the right sheet active when the code runs? Also, note that the dotted lines will not go away - but this code should move all implict page breaks to the edges of the print area.

Comment: The right sheet is active, see the new edit above, the landscape setting in the same section works. And the lines are still in the same place, in the middle of the spreadsheet. I'm trying to avoid a dynamic print area, but I suppose that's an option.

Comment: Side note, this sheet won't really ever be printed, so it doesn't matter if they are moved or simply invisible.

Comment: Hey I got it! We need a `Zoom = False` line also. See the 'Solution' section in my question. I've accepted your answer, please add this missing piece to it! Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: Zoom is in PageSetup also

Answer (score 2):

Write the following in the immediate window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = Not ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
```

Or simply write Or simpy write - `ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False` in VBA, at the end of your code.

[Worksheet.DisplayPageBreaks Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-displaypagebreaks-property-excel)

Comment: The sheet in question would have to be activated or selected first since Jackson is using the sheet name to navigate between sheets.  Jackson:  I tried your code in Excel 2007 and it worked for me.  I don't think the problem is in that particular line of code.

Comment: @Vityata "In the immediate window" You mean on the sheet? This all has to happen via VBA code. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you?

Comment: @jknight I think Mat's Mug up above has the right idea, fix it the right way in PageSetup

Comment: @Jackson - press Ctrl + G ti open the immedite window and write it there

Comment: Or simpy write - `ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False` in VBA, @Jackson

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Entering that code in the immediate window only removes them after it's already run. If I rerun they are back again.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False` is what I originally tried, which is not working. Evidently it should be working if it works in the immediate window. Why wouldn't it be working when run from the code?

Comment: @Jackson - it should be working, did you write it as a last line?

Comment: No, I can try it as the last line. Edited my question RE your suggestions btw

Comment: Did not work on the last line. See additional edit. Tried both `ActiveSheet` and specifying sheet name.

Answer (score 2):

The dotted lines are simply showing where the page will break. Has nothing to do with inserted page breaks. So removing page breaks doesn't do anything. The page will still break somewhere unless you specify one page wide/tall per Mats Mug.

If you don't want to see the dotted lines, just save, close and reopen. The lines are gone. Of course they will reappear when you preview or print.

It's a feature, not a flaw.

Comment: Specifying one page wide/tall did not move the page break lines. When using the same `.PageSetup` as on a different spreadsheet (different SQL portion), one shows the page breaks and one does not.

Comment: Moreover, saving and reopening doesn't solve it. This is a macro generated sheet that is regenerated by a user each time the data is needed. I understand that on a normal spreadsheet I can simply turn them off in the settings, save and reopen. Wish that were an option. As stated above, this has to come from the code, not from actions within the GUI.